# Optimising my SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a python application that pings devices as a test to check if they are alive or not.

Below is the query I use to group each of the devices, and determine if the device is online based on the last record in PingResults for that device

```
SELECT     
    c.ID, c.DeviceName, c.GroupID, c.DeviceIP, p1.Status, 
    p1.DateTime AS LastUpdate, DeviceGroups.GroupName
FROM         
    Devices AS c 
INNER JOIN
    PingResults AS p1 ON c.ID = p1.DeviceID 
INNER JOIN
    DeviceGroups ON c.GroupID = DeviceGroups.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PingResults AS p2 ON c.ID = p2.DeviceID 
                      AND (p1.DateTime < p2.DateTime OR
                           p1.DateTime = p2.DateTime AND p1.DeviceID < p2.DeviceID)
WHERE     
    (p2.ID IS NULL)
```

The query works, however it is currently taking 1:23 minuets to run with 44000 records in the pingResults table and 28 devices.

Output of the query

```
DeviceName  DeviceIP    GroupID ID  Status        LastUpdate           GroupName

Machine 25  192.168.0.226   1   114 True    2018-02-20 09:46:40.717 Machine Terminals
Machine 2   192.168.0.199   1   100 True    2018-02-20 09:48:09.113 Machine Terminals
Machine 3   192.168.0.229   1   101 True    2018-02-20 09:48:12.710 Machine Terminals
Machine 4   192.168.0.224   1   102 True    2018-02-20 09:48:15.123 Machine Terminals
Machine 5   192.168.0.218   1   103 True    2018-02-20 09:48:17.763 Machine Terminals
Machine 6   192.168.0.219   1   104 True    2018-02-20 09:48:19.823 Machine Terminals
Machine 7   192.168.0.217   1   105 False   2018-02-20 09:48:23.763 Machine Terminals
Machine 8   192.168.0.220   1   106 False   2018-02-20 09:48:26.763 Machine Terminals
```

Current execution plan

Is there any way i can optimise or change this query to be more effiecent, as at the current rate it's going to take too long to run when the database fills up.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PingResults AS p2 
   ON c.ID = p2.DeviceID AND (p1.DateTime < p2.DateTime 
      OR p1.DateTime = p2.DateTime AND p1.DeviceID < p2.DeviceID)
WHERE     (p2.ID IS NULL)
```

`-->`

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PingResults AS p2 
    WHERE c.ID = p2.DeviceID AND (p1.DateTime < p2.DateTime 
      OR p1.DateTime = p2.DateTime AND p1.DeviceID < p2.DeviceID)
)
```

And create clustered indexes for each table!

## upd

after another look at it:

```
SELECT  c.ID,
        c.DeviceName,
        c.GroupID,
        c.DeviceIP,
        p1.[Status],
        p1.LastUpdate,
        DeviceGroups.GroupName
FROM    Devices                  AS c   
        INNER JOIN  DeviceGroups
            ON  c.GroupID = DeviceGroups.ID   
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1 p1.[Status], p1.[DateTime] AS LastUpdate
            FROM PingResults  AS p1
            WHERE p1.DeviceID  = c.ID
            ORDER BY p1.DateTime DESC
        ) p1
```

No need for two "reads" of `PingResults`.

Another thing is:

```
ON c.ID = p2.DeviceID 
AND (p1.DateTime < p2.DateTime 
   OR p1.DateTime = p2.DateTime 
     AND p1.DeviceID < p2.DeviceID ---<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
)
```

Really? After `c.ID = p1.DeviceID` and `c.ID = p2.DeviceID`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help!, the first change you made put it at about 4 second execution time, the second made it almost instant.

Comment: Don't forget to create clustered indexes for each table.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.DeviceName, c.GroupID, c.DeviceIP, p1.Status, 
       p1.DateTime AS LastUpdate, dg.GroupName
FROM Devices c INNER JOIN
     PingResults p1
     ON c.ID = p1.DeviceID INNER JOIN
     DeviceGroups dg
     ON c.GroupID = dg.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PingResults p2
     ON c.ID = p2.DeviceID AND
        (p1.DateTime < p2.DateTime OR
         p1.DateTime = p2.DateTime AND p1.DeviceID < p2.DeviceID
        )
WHERE p2.ID IS NULL;
```

You want to be sure that you have indexes on:

- `PingResults(deviceId, datetime)`
- `DeviceGroups(id, groupname)`  (minor optimization)

You might also find that writing this with `row_number()` speeds the query:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.DeviceName, c.GroupID, c.DeviceIP, p1.Status, 
       p1.DateTime AS LastUpdate, dg.GroupName
FROM Devices c INNER JOIN
     (select p1.*, row_number() over (partition by deviceid order by datetime) as seqnum
      from PingResults p1
     ) p1
     ON c.ID = p1.DeviceID AND seqnum = 1 INNER JOIN
     DeviceGroups dg
     ON c.GroupID = dg.ID ;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, the row_number() version made the query run in less than 1 second

Comment: @joshkirkpatrick . . . In that case, I'm surprised that you did not accept this answer.

Comment: The other guy also gave an answer that made it instant, and he answered first, if i could i would accept both.

Comment: @joshkirkpatrick . . . That's fine.  You have a good reason and `cross apply` is a very good solution (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest cost in your plan is the Hash Match (Inner Join).

To speed that up, Index the two tables involved in the JOIN (Devices and DeviceGroups) on the columns that they JOIN on.

This should change the Hash Match to an Inner Loop, which is much faster as you can see in your plan.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should use row_number:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT  
    c.ID, 
    c.DeviceName, 
    c.GroupID, 
    c.DeviceIP, 
    p1.Status, 
    p1.DateTime,
    DeviceGroups.GroupName,
    row_number() over (partition by c.ID order by p1.DateTime desc) rn
  FROM
    Devices AS c
  INNER JOIN
    PingResults AS p1
  ON c.ID = p1.DeviceID
  INNER JOIN
    DeviceGroups
  ON c.GroupID = DeviceGroups.ID
)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  DeviceName, 
  GroupID, 
  DeviceIP, 
  Status, 
  DateTime LastUpdate,
  DeviceGroups.GroupName
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```